Can java.lang.InternalError stack trace be caputred using log4j2 file appender?
With my current configuration of log4j2 I can capture all Application logs and can direct them to both console and file.
When below error occurs. It is being captured on in console. How can I capture them in file mentioned in log4j2.xml?
Can VirtualMachine errors be captured by log4j2 file appender?
 java.lang.InternalError: Failed to load org.graalvm.jniutils.JNIExceptionWrapperEntryPoints
    at org.graalvm.jniutils/org.graalvm.jniutils.JNIExceptionWrapper$ExceptionHandlerContext.throwJNIExceptionWrapper(JNIExceptionWrapper.java:282)
    at org.graalvm.jniutils/org.graalvm.jniutils.JNIExceptionWrapper$ExceptionHandler$1.handleException(JNIExceptionWrapper.java:294)
    at org.graalvm.jniutils/org.graalvm.jniutils.JNIExceptionWrapper.wrapAndThrowPendingJNIException(JNIExceptionWrapper.java:175)
    at org.graalvm.jniutils/org.graalvm.jniutils.JNICalls.callStaticJObject(JNICalls.java:146)
    at com.oracle.svm.graal.hotspot.libgraal.truffle.FromLibGraalCalls.callJObject(FromLibGraalCalls.java:123)
    at com.oracle.svm.graal.hotspot.libgraal.truffle.HSTruffleCompilerRuntimeGen.callCreateStringSupplier(HSTruffleCompilerRuntimeGen.java:95)
    at com.oracle.svm.graal.hotspot.libgraal.truffle.HSTruffleCompilerRuntime.isSuppressedFailure(HSTruffleCompilerRuntime.java:247)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.truffle.compiler.TruffleCompilerImpl.isSuppressedFailure(TruffleCompilerImpl.java:755)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.truffle.compiler.TruffleCompilerImpl.doCompile(TruffleCompilerImpl.java:233)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.truffle.compiler.TruffleCompilerImpl.doCompile(TruffleCompilerImpl.java:205)
    at com.oracle.svm.graal.hotspot.libgraal.truffle.TruffleToLibGraalEntryPoints.doCompile(TruffleToLibGraalEntryPoints.java:245)
    Suppressed: java.lang.InternalError: Failed to load org.graalvm.jniutils.JNIExceptionWrapperEntryPoints
        at com.oracle.svm.graal.hotspot.libgraal.truffle.TruffleToLibGraalEntryPoints.doCompile(TruffleToLibGraalEntryPoints.java:250)


You need to post complete stacktrace.

Thats the full stack trace i received on console. I want to write to log file as well

Looks like this exception is caught somewhere in compiler internals. I doubt you can do something about it.

You application is logging using log4j2. The JVM is not.
